# What is the topology on frame bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

The Frame_bundle article of Wikipedia mentions that the topology of frame bundle (as a fiber bundle it should have a topology) is constructed "reversely" to make the "local trivialization candidates" homeomorphisms.

Suppose $e:E\to X$ is a vector bundle, $\pi:F(E)\to X$ is the "frame bundle candidate" (since this is in the process to define frame bundle), $\psi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times GL(k,R)$ is the "local trivilization candidates".

Then topologies are defined on each $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ to make them homeomorphic to $U_i\times GL(k,R)$. The problem is if $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $\pi^{-1}(U_j)$ have different open sets in $\pi^{-1}(U_i)\cap\pi^{-1}(U_j)$ then how can a topology be defined on $F(E)$ that is compatible with both? Note that if any open sets are added to or removed from the topology on $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$, then $\psi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times GL(k,R)$ won't be a homeomorphisms anymore. This seems to be what the article does, it define the topology on $F(E)$ with the final topology, i.e. removing "incompatible open sets" from the topologies for $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ which IMO make $\psi_i$ not homeomorphic anymore.

Comment: No.  Exercise for you: on intersections you don't gain additional open sets.

Comment: @user10354138 What process are you talking about in which you don't gain additional open sets? Final topology means removal of open sets and either addition or removal will break the homeomorphisms so I feel I don't get your point.